# Redirect only links with Uppercase to a new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect from domain1 only the links that has Uppercase letters only.

Example

www.domain1.com/K2L8 --> www.domain2.com/K2L8 (redirect)

www.domain1.com/aboutus --> www.domain1.com/aboutus (no redirect)

www.domain1.com --> www.domain1.com (no redirect)

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This should match what you want:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]+)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R]
```